# Maven version:update not updating the given version, it compares with the repo and update to the latest instead of given version

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I want to back patch my fix to one of my old version jar.
I have releases from  1.0.85, 1.0.86, 1.0.87, 1.0.88, 1.0.89 in my nexus repository.
I want update my fix  ie back patch the version 1.0.85
I will update the the parent pom version using version:update-parent and the new version i given as 
1.0.85_b1.
But it checks the repository and update the latest version from the nexus repo. ie 1.0.89.
Its not updating 1.0.85_b1.

`mvn -f pom.xml -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=1.0.85b1 -Dproperty=parentVersion versions:update-parent`

maven logs

`

```
    --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7:update-parent (default-cli) @ componet ---
[INFO] artifact com.xxxx.yyy:zzzz-aaaa: checking for updates from xxxxx
[INFO] artifact com.xxxx.yyy:zzzz-aaaa: checking for updates from xxxxx
[INFO] artifact com.xxxx.yyy:zzzz-aaaa: checking for updates from xxxxx
[INFO] artifact com.xxxx.yyy:zzzz-aaaa: checking for updates from xxxxx
[INFO] artifact com.xxxx.yyy:zzzz-aaaa: checking for updates from xxxxx
[INFO] artifact com.xxxx.yyy:zzzz-aaaa: checking for updates from xxxxx
[INFO] artifact com.xxxx.yyy:zzzz-aaaa: checking for updates from xxxxx
Downloading from nexus-xxx-rep: http://maven.xxxgroup.com/content/groups/all/com/xxx/xxx/componet-parent/1.0.89/componet-parent-1.0.89.pom
Downloaded from nexus-xxx-rep: http://maven.xxxgroup.com/content/groups/all/com/xxx/xxx/componet-parent/1.0.89/componet-parent-1.0.89.pom (4.8 kB at 5.4 kB/s)
[INFO] Updating parent from 1.0.85 to 1.0.89
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] componet proj DEV.0.0-SNAPSHOT .................... SUCCESS [  3.211 s]
[INFO] componet 1.0.85 ...................................... SUCCESS [ 11.108 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.352 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-17T21:02:34+05:30
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the parameter `parentVersion`. Here, you can set lower and upper bounds for the version you desire.

https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-parent.html

Comment: I tried like this mvn -f pom.xml -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=1.0.85_x -Dproperty=parentVersion -DparentVersion=[1.0.85,1.0.89) versions:update-parent

Comment: It directly downloads the hotfix version and updated as Current version of com.xxxxxxxx.zzz:abced-parent:pom:1.0.87_hotfix2 is the latest.[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from nexus-AB-rep: http://maven.xxxxxxxxgroup.com/content/groups/all/com/xxxxxxxx/zzz/abced-parent/1.0.87_hotfix2/abced-parent-1.0.87_hotfix2.pom
Downloaded from nexus-AB-rep: http://maven.xxxxxxxxgroup.com/content/groups/all/com/xxxxxxxx/zzz/abced-parent/1.0.87_hotfix2/abced-parent-1.0.87_hotfix2.pom (4.8 kB at 4.9 kB/s)
[WARNING]

Comment: 1.0.85,1.0.89 this range omitted. But taken the 1.0.87_hotfix2 this one, how to avoid that one also

Comment: Define a range like `[1.0.85_b1]`

Comment: Hi JF Meier if i used mvn versions:set -DallowSnapshots=false -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DnewVersion=${versioninversion.properties} in script it asked for Enter the new version to set DEV.0.0-SNAPSHOT: i manually enter the value, it doesn't  taken form the version.properties file

Comment: @PonmanikandanBoothalingam This is a different question, isn't it? Please ask a new question on SO instead of adding a comment.